# Average of $\lambda(n+1)$ for $n$ smooth, or smooth-and-rough? What follows?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, multiplicative-number-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the Liouville function, i.e., $\lambda(p_1\dotsb p_k)=(-1)^k$ for $p_1,\dotsc,p_k$ not necessarily distinct.

There is a conjecture (due to whom?) that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\lambda(p+1)=1$, and infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\lambda(p+1)=-1$.

(a) Is it known that there are infinitely many numbers $n$ that are $n^{1/\log \log n}$-smooth (say) (meaning: numbers having no prime factors $> n^{1/\log \log n}$) such that $\lambda(n+1)=1$, or $\lambda(n+1)=-1$? What would follow if we knew that $\lambda(n+1)=1$ and $\lambda(n+1)=-1$ are about as common for $n^{1/\log \log n}$-smooth numbers?

(b) Same questions, but for numbers $n$ that are both $n^{1/\log \log n}$-smooth and (say) $\exp((\log n)^{1/4})$-rough (meaning they have no prime divisors smaller than $\exp((\log n)^{1/4})$).

---

(I am not asking the same questions for numbers $n$ that are just rough - I think this kind of result would not then be particularly hard (sieve theory + Bombieri-Vinogradov).)

Comment: For (a) with $\lambda(n+1)=1$, you can take $n = m^2-1 = (m-1)(m+1)$, and I assume it's known that there are infinitely many $m$ with $m-1$ and $m+1$ both $m^{1/\log\log m}$ smooth, but I could be wrong. For $\lambda(n+1) = -1$, maybe there are good enough results now about smoothness of $p-1$.

Comment: Self-remark: there is Joni Teräväinen's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01195.pdf . Better bounds are known by now (the paper does not make its bounds explicit, but its error terms are presumably of size O(1/log log log) - are there any applications in which a smaller error term is crucial?